# Understanding Task and TaskGroup cancellation in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

In Swift Concurrency when Tasks are cancelled, child tasks and task groups are also implicitly canceled, [according to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/iscancelled) and [WWDC talks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10134/?time=611). However, when I implement work in a TaskGroup and cancel its parent task, I'm unable to get it to recognize it has been cancelled.

Below is a short example demonstrating the problem.

The function `start` starts a Task that spins up a TaskGroup and adds a task to it every 2 seconds. Two seconds in, `cancel()` is called on the Task. I expect that one or two of the resulting values is marked as not completed. However, even after cancellation they're all marked as completed, meaning they did not respect `addTaskUnlessCancelled`.

```swift
public struct Thing {
    let completed: Bool
    let value: Int?
}

public struct TaskGroupCancellation {
    public mutating func start() async {
        let task = Task {
            let things = await withTaskGroup(of: Thing.self, returning: [Thing].self, body: { group in
                print("withTaskGroup start")
                var t = [Thing]()
                for i in 0..<3 {
                    let isCancelled = group.isCancelled
                    let added = group.addTaskUnlessCancelled {
                        print("Adding value \(i) (canceled?: \(isCancelled))")
                        return Thing(completed: true, value: i)
                    }
                    if !added {
                        print("Marking value \(i) as cancelled")
                        t.append(Thing(completed: false, value: nil))
                    }
                    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
                }

                for await thing in group {
                    t.append(thing)
                }
                print("withTaskGroup end")

                return t
            })

            print("Things: \(things)")
        }

        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        task.cancel()
        print("Cancelled")
    }
}
```

Running the above yields the following output:

```
withTaskGroup start
Adding value 0 (canceled?: false)
Cancelled
Adding value 2 (canceled?: false)
Adding value 1 (canceled?: false)
withTaskGroup end
Things: [TaskGroupCancellation.Thing(completed: true, value: Optional(0)), TaskGroupCancellation.Thing(completed: true, value: Optional(2)), TaskGroupCancellation.Thing(completed: true, value: Optional(1))]
```

I'm expecting the task group's `addTaskUnlessCancelled` to not be entered after cancellation, but it seems like it still is. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the last line of your output. The task is cancelled, so the `things` array can't be printed.

Comment: I wonder if I left off some important detail. I built this as a Swift package and ran it (and got the above output) from a unit test. This is on Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: To make sure the problem wasn't my execution environment, I did the following:

1. I created a new macOS SwiftUI project.
2. I copied the above code in and converted the struct to a `class ViewModel: ObservableObject`.
3. I made the task a property (i.e. `private var task: Task<(), Error>? = nil`).
4. I added a `stop()` func that calls `cancel()` on the task.
5. I hooked up `start()` and `stop()` to a button in the UI.

I got the same results. `cancel()` is called on the task but the TaskGroup's isCanceled is `false` and the `addTaskUnlessCancelled` block is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experience the same `TaskGroup` behavior.

The `TaskGroup` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/iscancelled) for `isCancelled` says:

> If the task that’s currently running this group is canceled, the group is also implicitly canceled, which is also reflected in this property’s value.

That caveat about the broader task cancelation will be “reflected in this property’s value” has not been my experience. I find that if the parent task is canceled, the group is canceled alright, but neither the `group.isCancelled` value nor `addTaskUnlessCancelled` method reflect this.

To get around this, you can `try Task.checkCancellation()` (or examine `Task.isCancelled`), as that obviously does correctly represent whether this task has been canceled.

Or alternatively, it generally isn't necessary to do anything and just let the automatic propagation of cancelation take care of everything. E.g., consider:

```swift
import os.log

let poi = OSSignposter(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

func experimentCancelingParentTask() async throws {
    let task = Task {
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            let id = poi.makeSignpostID()
            let state = poi.beginInterval("group", id: id)

            defer {
                let groupIsCancelled = group.isCancelled
                poi.endInterval("group", state, "group.isCancelled = \(groupIsCancelled.description); Task.isCancelled = \(Task.isCancelled.description)")
            }

            for await value in tickSequence() {
                poi.emitEvent("tick", "\(value)")
                group.addTask { try await self.performTask(with: value) }
            }

            try await group.waitForAll()
        }
    }

    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(4.5))
    poi.emitEvent("cancel")
    task.cancel()
}
```

If I profile that in Instruments with the “Points of Interest” tool, I will see:

[image]

Note that `group.isCancelled` is `false`, but `Task.isCancelled` is `true`. But, regardless, when the task group was canceled (that last Ⓢ signpost), the tasks that were in-flight were canceled, and even the `AsyncSequence` that this task group was iterating through was canceled.

---

With all of that having been said, it is worth noting that `group.cancelAll()` results in the group cancelation state being reflected by `group.isCancelled` and `addTaskUnlessCancelled`. I know that `group.cancelAll()` was not the question at hand, but I wanted to note that this group-cancelation logic basically works, but merely does not reflect the cancelation state of the parent task.

But as shown above, that is generally not needed, anyway.

---

It's not terribly relevant, but here are a few functions that the above code snippet used:

```swift
// just a placeholder function to perform a task (and log stuff for “Points of Interest”); 
// the only salient detail is that this supports cancelation

func performTask(with value: Int) async throws {
    let id = poi.makeSignpostID()
    let state = poi.beginInterval("task", id: id, "\(value)")

    defer {
        poi.endInterval("task", state, "\(value)")
    }

    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.75))
}

// a sequence of 12 values yielded one per second

func tickSequence() -> AsyncStream<Int> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        let task = Task {
            for i in 0 ..< 100 {
                continuation.yield(i)
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }

        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```